# JasperReports fillReport too slow and resource consuming

Tags: java, xml, performance, jasper-reports

I've found that JasperReports is really **slow** when filling a report from a Java app. The program hangs at this line:

```
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, xmlDataSource);
```

It usually stays there for **3 minutes, consuming up to 300Mb of RAM and 50% CPU**.

- `report` is a compiled (.jasper) report that uses 3 subreports.
- The datasource is a pretty big XML file (about 100k lines, 1.5Mb)
- The machine is a 3Ghz dual core with 4Gb of RAM

So, how can I improve report filling performance?

Comment: DO you have the stats of how the performance is after you switched to xalan ?

Comment: @vsingh As I said in the answer: "While the report filling was taking 3-5 minutes with Xalan, it now completes in just a few seconds with Jaxen"

Comment: Are you using virtualizer ? We are facing challenges to generate large reports. In this case we pass in the complete data set https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467407/large-report-generation-with-jasper-using-virtualizer-takes-too-much-time

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### The Problem

It seems that the problem is the XPath engine. That is, the library that parses the XML file looking for data.

While iReport Designer uses **Jaxen**, JasperReport uses **Xalan**. Xalan is really slow compared to Jaxen (really really slow).

That's why the problem only occurs when filling the report from a Java application and not from iReports.

#### The Solution

Well, the solution is simple, <strike>just add the following line in your Java application to select Jaxen lib instead of the default Xalan lib (it's deprecated, but it works):</strike>

```
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
    "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");
```

**EDIT**: That line was deprecated, I've found the correct way to set properties:

```
DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
    "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");
```

You will also need to add the Jaxen .jar to your build path. Here is a link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen

---

*While the report filling was taking 3-5 minutes with Xalan, it now completes in just a few seconds with Jaxen.*

The answer was found here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/536842/jasperreports-too-slow 
And also here: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/xml-data-source-very-slow-parse

Comment: jasper report version 6.3.1 is much faster than Jaxen

Comment: As of 6.4.1, changing to jaxen results in a 5:1 reduction in XML processing time for content size in the vicinity of 1MB. So yeah, still an awesome solution, thanks a bunch.

Comment: What will be the alternative to this solution if the datasource is not XML but a JRDataSource set as a parameter in the report?

Answer (score 6):

I was also having this problem when I was exporting pdf, but in my case it seemed to be an infinite loop, because the CPU was hitting 100% when I was trying to generate the JasperReport.

After a lot of research I found this link:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527078/infinite-loop-subreport-fill

Which my problem was resolved setting my subreports `isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="false"`.

Comment: Great, you saved my time!!!

Comment: We've had the very same problem for months already with reports running for several days and ending by crashing the server with an out-of-memory.
Switching that property to false solved it. Report is now being generated within few minutes.
Thanks for pointing this out.