# Slow JasperReports fill time even for blank page

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a **small** report that, for this particular project, needs to be rendered fast. I haven't noticed this before, but it seems that even for rendering an actual **blank** page with no data source nor any on-page elements *JasperFillManager.fillReport* takes at least **1.5** (one and a half) seconds to complete.

In other words, "filling" a blank, compiled JasperReport into a JasperPrint object, before even exporting it to PDF for example, takes **1.5s** which seems a lot (the export is way under 100ms). I wonder if there is anything to improve the performance of the fill stage?

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Are you using an XML file as datasource? Check this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875199/jasperreports-fillreport-too-slow-and-resource-consuming