# Jasper Report - How to change xpath executer factory

Tags: java, xpath, report

I was checking the following question [JasperReports fillReport too slow and resource consuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875199/jasperreports-fillreport-too-slow-and-resource-consuming) and I tried to apply the verfied answer but couldn't notice any change in the generation of my reports.

Basicaly what I'm trying to do is to change the xpath executer factory for JasperFillManager to use Jaxen instead of Xalan but I can't seem to know where I should place the following line in my code

```
    DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
    JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
                                                      "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");
```

My code block looks as follows

```
private JasperPrint getJasperPrintInstance(JasperReport report) throws JRException, NamingException, SQLException {
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;
    DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
    JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
                                                      "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");
    if (dataSource == null) {
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, this.reportParams, connection);
    } else {
        jasperPrint =
            JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, this.reportParams,
                                         new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(getDataSource()));
    }

    return jasperPrint;
}
```

Even when I change "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory" to anything else nothing changes.

Can you please let me know what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are not using the newly created `context`. You need to create a `JasperFillManager` instance with it:

`JasperFillManager jasperFillManager = JasperFillManager.getInstance(context);`

and use that with its instance methods instead of the class ones like so:

`jasperPrint = jasperFillManager.fill(report, this.reportParams, connection);`

Comment: For me, the speed is still the same. Is there an alternative in 2021?