# Large report generation with Jasper using Virtualizer takes too much time

Tags: java, performance, jasper-reports

We are using Japser to generate reports  in our application

We have upgraded from 5.0.1 to 6.4 to achive better performance but this is what we are not seeing good results after few test runs. It takes approximately 44 mins to generate the report

This is our configuration

Jasper version : 6.4

JDK 1.7

Server : tomcat 7 , 3GB RAM

Number of records : 850k

We get the results from database and hand it over to jasper.

Below is the memory consumption and CPU utilization when generating the report

[image]

```
JRSwapFile swapFile = new JRSwapFile(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), 4096, 25);
JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(2, swapFile, true);
virtualizer.setReadOnly(false);
context.getReportParams().put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);
```

Looking for suggestions on how to reduce report generation time with lower memory consumption. 
is that how the reports are supposed to perform for this large dataset or we are doing something wrong here ?

We are using JRSwapFileVirtualizer. When virtualizer was not used, then time taken to generate report was better but we could not generate large reports.
Should we use another virtualizer like Gzip virtualizer or tweak parameters for  File Virtualizer like 
maxSize, blockSize and minGrowCount parameters.

Update : 
Tried with GzipVirtualizer but not much difference in timings or memory consumption

Comment: The graph makes it pretty obvious - you're using very little CPU and a ton of memory.  My smartwatch has more memory than you're running on - run it on a real machine with 8+ GB of memory and run a 64 bit JVM.  Swaping to disk is going to make it incredibly slow.

Comment: this is 64 bit jvm but not sure how throwing more memory will solve the issue. Is it expected for jasper to consume so much memory and take so long to generate the report ?

Comment: If you're using a swap file then I'm impressed you're doing as well as you are.  Memory is several orders of magnitude faster than disk, even if you're using an SSD.  So using disk as memory is going to slow things down a significant amount.